# Call interface method implemented in an activity from a java class

Tags: android, interface

I want to call an interface method implemented in activity A from a java class where web apis are written.

Flow is like moving from activity A to activity B and from activity B an api written in a separate java class is called, now on successful result of api, I want to invoke the interface method implemented in Activity A.

A -> B -> Java class -> interface() in A

I am facing problem in getting reference of activity A in java class for calling interface method. I have tried follwing code but nothing worked. Thanks for your time and help

```
Interface objInterface =  (Interface) context;
objInterface.funInterface();

Interface objInterface =  (Interface) context.getApplicationContext();
objInterface.funInterface();

Interface objInterface =  (Interface) new Activity_A;
objInterface.funInterface();
```

Comment: try using EventBus its so simple.   You don't need to use interface  https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: If I understand, do you want to call an interface method that implements activity A in a Java class? If yes, so you can get the reference to activity A by passing the context and then doing Interface i = (ActivityA) context;

Comment: @RaffaeleD'Arco its like context is passed from ActivityB and casting it to ActivityA

Comment: Try Interface interface = (Interface) context. This works when I want to communicate a fragment with an activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me describe what you're trying to do and maybe you'll see why you're having a hard time:

---

```
Interface objInterface =  (Interface) context;
objInterface.funInterface();
```

If this `context` is from Activity B, then this is wrong. Activity B and Activity A are both `Context`s, but they are not the same `Context`.

---

```
Interface objInterface =  (Interface) context.getApplicationContext();
objInterface.funInterface();
```

The `Application` is not the same as an `Activity`. It cannot magically become Activity A.

---

```
Interface objInterface =  (Interface) new Activity_A;
objInterface.funInterface();
```

This is definitely an Activity A and it *does* have the implementation... but it is a different A than the one that was already existing.

---

Activity B shouldn't know about Activity A. Your separate java class shouldn't know about Activity B. This is a common design principle called [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). I suggest focus on getting data from your java class to Activity B first. Then, take that data and send it back to Activity A using the documented means of communicating between activities: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Finally, you can use a communication library like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), but looking at your code it seems like you might be misunderstanding a core concept so I wouldn't recommend relying on a "magical data bus" until you understand the scope of android components. :)